# Scully static server won't serve urls with percent-encoded space

Tags: scully, scullyio, angular-scully

My angular app contains percent-encoded routes. Ex. /Page%201

When I run my angular app with `ng serve` everything works fine.

But when I start the Scully static server and visit
"http://localhost:1668/Page%201", the browser shows

> Cannot GET /Page%201

I looked into my `./dist/static/assets/scully-routes.json` and I can see the `,{"route":"/Page%201"}`.

This behavior doesn't happen on routes without space.

Ex. `http://localhost:1668/Page2` works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The scully static server serves files matching the unescaped URI. In your case, when you enter `http://localhost:1668/Page%201`, the server will try to find a folder named `/Page 1` which doesn't exist.

### Solution 1: Frontend Side

After scully has generated the `dist/static` folder, rename all escaped name to their unescaped name. Ex. `/foo%20bar/` to `/foo bar/`.

### Solution 2: Server Side

Using nginx, I added this line to my `nginx.conf`:

```
      try_files $uri $uri/ $request_uri/index.html /index.html;
```

$uri is escaped and $request_uri is unescaped.

It will try `/foo bar`, then `/foo bar/` and then `/foo%20bar/index.html` which will find a match.

### Advice

If you can, just use ASCII in your urls.